# is there a way to return data from mongoose? Typescript, NestJS

Tags: typescript, mongoose, nestjs

I am working with nestjs and mongoose. is there a correct way to return the data or simplify this code? especially let response = ....

**pets.controller.ts**

```
.
.

//getPets
@Get('read')
async getPets(@Req() _req: Request, @Res() _res: Response) {


    let response: HttpResponse = await this.petService.getAll()
        .then(result => {
            return {
                code: HttpStatus.OK,
                ok: true,
                message: result,
            }

        }).catch(err => {
            return {
                code: HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
                ok: true,
                message: err,
            }
        });

    return _res.status(response.code).json(response);
}
```

**pets.service.ts**

```
//READ ALL
async getAll(): Promise<PetInterface[]> {

    return await this.petsModel.find();
}
```

or some good practices that are used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Here are some problems with the code**

1. Do not use `await` with `then()`. `await` wraps the statement in `then()`.
2. You don't need to write HTTP errors on your own. NestJS provides plenty of [default ones](https://docs.nestjs.com/exception-filters#built-in-http-exceptions).
3. If you need to write your own errors, use [exception filters](https://docs.nestjs.com/exception-filters) to catch them and write your own
   logic for custom errors.
4. Don't inject `@Req` and `@Res` everywhere. Make use of [DTOs](https://docs.nestjs.com/controllers#request-payloads). It is a lifesaver.
5. Always try to return the response in a DTO or an interface.
6. Try to handle the errors where it is relevant. Not in controllers(not always)

**How to do it in the NestJS Way :**

**pets.controller.ts**

```
//getPets
@Get('read')
public async getPets() {
    return await this.petService.getAll();
}
```

**pets.service.ts**

```
//READ ALL
public async getAll(): Promise<PetResponseDTO[]> {
    try{
       const petsQueryResult = await this.petsModel.find();
        return PetResponseDTO.listOfPetsFromQueryResult(petsQueryResult);
        }catch (e){
         //Whatever you want to do with the error.
         //...
         //Imported from @nestjs/common
         throw new BadRequestException('<Reason>');
         // OR
         throw new InternalServerErrorException();
        }
}
```

**pet.response.dto**

```
export class PetResponseDTO{

 public static listOfPetsFromQueryResult(petsQueryResult:<query result type>[]): PetResponseDTO[]{
     const listOfAllPets = [];
     for(const pet of petsQueryResult){
      listOfAllPets.push(new PetResponseDTO(id,name,petType));
    }
   return listOfAllPets;
  }

 constructor(id:string,name:string,petType:string){
   this.id = id;
   this.petType = petType;
   this.name = name;
  }

 id: string;
 name: string;
 petType: string;
//....Whatever fields you want
}
```

Comment: What happens when I want to send a reply like this? In this case a JSON ({ code: HttpStatus.OK, ok: true, message: result, } ). I need to use Res. Also Req in my Post requests. Not just Body

Comment: You can can use [interceptors](https://docs.nestjs.com/interceptors#response-mapping) for the routes. You'll get the entire response and request object from the [execution context](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/execution-context#execution-context). You can check the response, map the custom data format and send it back.

Answer (score 2):

Also, extending SPS answer about Mongo itself.

If you returning documents for API responses, you don't need the Mongoose document itself. A lean version of them will be fine and much less heavy. So add `.lean()` to your queries, like `await this.petsModel.find().lean()` (or pass it as a `{ query: option }`). The interface type will be `LeanDocument<Doctype>` for a single document.

The second thing is: don't return all documents in one query. It's ok for study purposes, but not for production. Add `limit` to your query, make a pagination with `limit` and `skip`, or stream data via `cursor()`.

Comment: Yap.. this is a great optimization. I totally looked over it.